# how add flash through php?

Tags: php

how add flash through php?

Comment: Put in just a hint more effort please.

Comment: Please refine your question. It is not possible to help you with this information

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish (in slightly more detail, if you could - as it stands now, it's not clear at all)? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Comment: You add flash with the flash switch on a camera. Nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

1. this question is quite 'thin'
2. php is most being used for constructing html contents
3. in the html content you embed your flash like this:

   http://www.w3schools.com/flash/flash_inhtml.asp